# Proving: $f$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow f(X \cap Y) = f(X) \cap f(Y)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditions Equivalent to Injectivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79287/conditions-equivalent-to-injectivity)

Let $A$ := "$f$ is injective" and $B$ := "$f(X \cap Y) = f(X) \cap f(Y)$".

My first idea is to show $B \implies A$ through contraposition, so $\lnot A \implies \lnot B$. Would it then be enough if I say: $f$ is not injective and then show an example where the equation in $B$ is wrong? Would it be a proof then?

Comment: It is not an exact duplicate question, my question is more general, my question is that if want to show not A => not B is proved if i say f is not injective and have an example where b is not true, if that  is enough to count as a proof

Comment: I bumped up the post @Jay. Let's see if anyone wants the post reopened.

Comment: Jay: If you mean that **for every non-injective $f$** you find an example of sets $X$, $Y$ for which the equality fails, then yes; this is a correct proof.