# Help with set theory proofs ((For all A, B ⊆ X: f ( A \ B ) = f ( A ) \ f ( B )) <==> f is injective)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

**Edit: by now I've figured out i<=>ii! Just not iii<=>i**

For an assignment I need to prove the following: i<=>ii<=>iii.
My approach was to prove i<=>ii and i<=>ii. I'm mainly getting stuck on the 'iii<=>i' parts here.

(i)
f
is injective

(ii) For all
A, B
⊆
X: 
f
(
A
∩
B
) =
f
(
A
)
∩
f
(
B
).

(iii) For all
A, B
⊆
X:
f
(
A
\
B
) =
f
(
A
)
\
f
(
B
).

I saw a proof like this before, but I did not really understand all of the answers, and as the question was posted years ago, I thought it'd be better to post my own question.

Comment: For the diference, see also: [If $f$ is 1-1, prove that $f(A\setminus B) = f(A)\setminus f(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/944683) and [Does $f(X \setminus A)\subseteq Y\setminus f(A), \forall A\subseteq X$ imply $f$ is injective ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1319371)

Comment: For the intersection see [Conditions Equivalent to Injectivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79287) and [Proving: $f$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow f(X \cap Y) = f(X) \cap f(Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79331).

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ is injective and take an arbitrary $y$ in $f(A\backslash B)$. Since $f$ is injective, there is a unique $x$ such that $f(x)=y\in f(A\backslash B)$. For this $x$ we have that $x\in A\backslash B$ so $x\in A$ and $x\not\in B$, so $f(x)\in f(A)$ and $f(x)\not\in f(B)$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, $f(A\backslash B)\subset f(A)\backslash f(B)$. (i)

Now take a $y$ in $f(A)\backslash f(B)$, so $y\in f(A)$ and  $y\not\in f(B)$. Again, since $f$ is injective, there is a unique $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. So for this $x$ we have $x\in A$ and $x\not\in B$, so $x\in A\backslash B$, so $f(x)=y\in f(A\backslash B)$. So $f(A)\backslash f(B)\subset f(A\backslash B)$. (ii)

Thus from (i) and (ii) we conclude that if $f$ is injective, $f(A)\backslash f(B)=f(A\backslash B)$. This establishes the forward implication($\Rightarrow$).

Now assume that $f(A)\backslash f(B)=f(A\backslash B)$ for all $A,B \in X$. Take an $f(x)=y\in f(A\backslash B)=f(A)\backslash f(B)$. Thus if $x\in A\backslash B$, then $f(x)\in A$ and $f(x)\not\in B$. (iii)

Now assume that $f$ is not injective. Then there exist $x_1,x_2\in X$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Choose disjoint sets $A,B$ such that $x_1\in A$ and $x_2\in B$. Then we have from (iii) that  for $x_1\in A$ so $x_1\not\in B$ (because $A$ and $B$ are disjoint) that $y=f(x_1)\in f(A\backslash B)=f(A)\backslash f(B)$. So $y\not\in f(B)$. This is contradiction since we assumed that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and since $x_2\in B$, $f(x_2)\in f(B)$, thus $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\in B$. Because assuming $f$ is not injective leads to a contradiction, $f$ must be injective.

So if $f(A)\backslash f(B)=f(A\backslash B)$, then $f$ is injective. This establishes the backward implication($\Leftarrow$).

Comment: I don't quite understand this step:
''Since f is injective, there is a unique x such that f(x)=y∈f(A∖B). For this x we have that x∈A\B''

I know that if f is injective that if f(a)∈f(A) --> a ∈ A, but how does this follow from its definition?

Comment: The $x$ is unique, that is what follows from the defintion of injectivity. For a given $y$, there is a unique $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. Because $y\in f(A\backslash B)$, we conclude furthermore that $x\in A\backslash B$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the above equivalence as follows:
(i)$\Rightarrow$(ii)$\Rightarrow$(iii)$\Rightarrow$ (i)

**(i)**$\Rightarrow$**(ii)**
Suppose $f$ is injective. Then to show that $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B).$

let $x\in f(A\cap B)$. There exists some $y\in A\cap B$ such that $f(y)=x.$
$$\Rightarrow f(y)=x, y\in A\  \text{and}\  f(y)=x,\ y\in  B$$
$$\Rightarrow x\in f(A)\  \text{and}\  x\in  f(B)$$
$$\Rightarrow x\in f(A)\cap  f(B)$$
$$\Rightarrow f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap  f(B)$$

conversely, suppose $z\in f(A)\cap  f(B)$ Then,
$$ z=f(u)\ \text{and}\ z=f(v)\ \text{for some } u\in A \text{and} \ v\in B$$
$$\Rightarrow f(u)=f(v)$$
$$\Rightarrow u=v \text{ (since $f$ is injective)}$$
$$\Rightarrow u=v\in A\cap B$$
$$\Rightarrow z\in f(A\cap B)$$
$$f(A)\cap  f(B) \subseteq f(A\cap B)$$

**(ii)**$\Rightarrow $**(iii)**

suppose (ii) is true. Then $f(A\setminus B)=f(A\cap B^c)=f(A)\cap  f(B^c)=f(A)\cap  f(B)^c=f(A)\setminus  f(B)$

**(iii)$\Rightarrow$ (i)**

We prove the contrapositive.

Suppose $f$ is not injective. Then for some $x\neq y$ we must have
$f(x)=f(y)$. let $x\in A$ and $y\in X\setminus A$

Then $f(y)\in f(X\setminus A)=f(X)\setminus f(A)$ which  implies that $f(y)\notin f(A)$ BUT we already have $f(y0=f(x)\in f(A)$- Contradiction. This implies that
$f(A\setminus B)\neq f(A)\setminus  f(B)$. Thus (iii)$\Rightarrow$(i) is established.

Comment: Isn't ''f(A)∩f(Bc)=f(A)∩f(B)c'' exactly what needs to be proven (and can thus not be used?) Because Bc is another way of writing A\B.

Comment: Yes, I agree.Actually here we need to show that $f(A^c)=f(A)^c$

Comment: Just to add to previous comments, the problem with (ii)$\Rightarrow$(iii) is that it implicitly uses $f(B^c)=f(B)^c$. What this actually means depends on what we take as the universal set in the [definition of complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Absolute_complement). One possible interpretation $f(X\setminus B)=Y\setminus f(B)$, which is definitely not true for functions which are not surjective. Another possible interpretation would be $f(A\setminus B)=f(A)\setminus f(B)$, which is actually the claim we are trying to prove.