# Is this proof correct for : Does $F(A)\cap F(B)\subseteq F(A\cap B) $ for all functions $F$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Is this proof correct? To prove $F(A)\cap F(B)\subseteq F(A\cap B)  $ for all functions $F$.

> Let any number $y\in F(A)\cap F(B)$. We want to show $y\in F(A\cap B).$
>
> Therefore, $y\in F(A)$ and $y\in F(B)$, by definition of intersection.
>
> By definition of inverse, $y=F(x)$ for some $x\in A$ and $x\in B$
>
> And so, $y=F(x)$ for some $x\in A\cap B$
>
> And therefore, $y\in F(A\cap B)$

I have a gut feeling deep down that something is wrong. Can anyone help me pinpoint the mistake? I am not sure why am I having so much problems with functions. Am I not thinking in the right direction?

Sources : 2nd Ed, P219 9.60 = 3rd Ed, P235 9.12, 9.29 - *Mathematical Proofs*, by Gary Chartrand,
P214 Theorem 12.4 - *Book of Proof*, by Richard Hammack,
P257-258 - *How to Prove It*, by D Velleman.

Comment: Remark: $F(A) \cap F(B) \subseteq F(A \cap B)$ holds for all $A,B$ iff $F$ is one-to-one (injective).

Comment: If $F$ is injective and $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint, then will equality hold?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The third line is mistaken. You only know that there exists an $x$ in $A$ such that $F(x)=y$, and you know there is a $z\in B$ such that $F(z)=y$.

It is extremely easy to find a counterexample: just draw two sets $A$, $B$ that are disjoint, and map an $a\in A$ and a $b\in B$ to a single point. Then you have that $y\in F(A)\cap F(B)$, but $F(A\cap B)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @AustinMohr True, but I think in this case, since it really is extremely easy, the OP will need to have skin thick enough to not go crying into their beer about it. At any rate I applaud the OP's gut instinct!

Comment: If I sounded harsh, the compensation is that I +1 the question! Hope it helps...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 16):

Your gut is right. Something is indeed very wrong: the statement that you’re trying to prove is false. Here’s a familiar counterexample: let $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto x^2$, let $A$ be the set of negative real numbers, and let $B$ be the set of positive real numbers. Then $F[A]=F[B]=B$, so $F[A]\cap F[B]=B$, but $A\cap B=\varnothing$, so $F[A\cap B]=\varnothing$. Clearly $B\nsubseteq\varnothing$!

The problem with your reasoning, as you can see from the counterexample, is that although $x\in F[A]$ guarantees that $x=F(a)$ for some $a\in A$, and $x\in F[B]$ guarantees that $x=F(b)$ for some $b\in B$, you have no guarantee that $a=b$. There may be nothing at all in $A\cap B$.

Comment: And if one were to impose a restriction that A and B are not disjoint?

Comment: @Ahron: It wouldn’t really help. With the same function $F$ let $A=(\leftarrow,1]$ and $B=[-1,\to)$; then $f[A]=[0,\to)=f[B]$, so $f[A]\cap f[B]=[0,\to)$, but $A\cap B=[-1,1]$, and $f[A\cap B]=[0,1]\ne[0,to)$.

Comment: But if $F$ is injective, then equality holds, right? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79287/conditions-equivalent-to-injectivity

Comment: @Ahron: Yes, that’s correct. (And the last bit of my previous comment should have read ‘but $A\cap B=[-1,1]$, so $f[A\cap B]=[0,1]$, and $[0,\to)\nsubseteq[0,1]$.)

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. Consider $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{3,4\}$ and we can define $F(1)=F(3)=1,a$ not equal $c$ and this $A\cap B= \emptyset$ while $F(A)\cap F(B)$ doesn't equal to $\emptyset$. This is a counter example to your statement

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here, $f: A \rightarrow B$ is in green and $\{S_i\} = S_i$ for $S = A, B$ and $i = 1, 2.$
This picture proves that
$ f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) \not\subseteq f(A_1 \cap A_2)$. Incidentally, the same picture works for [Proving $f(C) \setminus f(D) \subseteq f(C \setminus D)$ and disproving equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511662/proving-fc-setminus-fd-subseteq-fc-setminus-d-and-disproving-equality).