# If $f(\bigcap_{\alpha\in{I}}A_\alpha)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in{I}}f(A_\alpha)$ then $f$ is an injection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I know that if $f$ is an injection then $f(\bigcap_{\alpha\in{I}}A_\alpha)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in{I}}f(A_\alpha)$ but, the inverse is true?. I mean If $f(\bigcap_{\alpha\in{I}}A_\alpha)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in{I}}f(A_\alpha)$ then $f$ is an injection

I would appreciate if you explain your answer please.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @alejopelaez: then for two disjoint sets the claimed property does not hold

Comment: @Ilya yes, you are right, I was a bit hasty

Comment: [Closely related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79287/conditions-equivalent-to-injectivity?rq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ for some $x_1\neq x_2$. Then $\{x_1\}\cap\{x_2\}=\emptyset$ so $f(\{x_1\}\cap\{x_2\})=\emptyset$. But $\{f(x_1)\}\cap\{f(x_2)\}\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: thanks @Hui Yu, I forgot to say that  $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha\in{I}}$ is a family of subsets of $X$ and $f: X\to Y$. Therefore f is an inyection in $X$?

Comment: forgive it, I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: @FernandoValle That's fine. Welcome to the site. If you are satisfied, you can probably check the tick and accept my answer.