# Prove that $f(A \backslash S) = B \backslash f(S)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

If $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a bijection and $S \subseteq A$, prove that $f(A \backslash S) = B \backslash f(S)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overview of basic results about images and preimages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages), and see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944683/if-f-is-1-1-prove-that-fa-setminus-b-fa-setminus-fb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in B$. One has $$x \in f(A \setminus S) \Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(x) \in A \setminus S \Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(x) \notin S \Longleftrightarrow x \notin f(S) \Longleftrightarrow x \in B \setminus f(S)$$

Comment: I think instead of $\Leftrightarrow$ (iff) you meant $\Rightarrow$, right? Because that's not the only case where x is not in f(A\S).

Comment: No, I mean $\Longleftrightarrow$, i.e. "iff". What bothers you ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see why now. Thanks.